# adding input file in immunity debugger

Tags: debugging, input, exe, disassembly

I have an exe file which is a program that has to get an input data file. I trying to run it in the immunity debugger. How can I add an input file there to run it correctly? I didnt find the option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add them in the opening window when chosing the file to debug